# Flattening a HashMap of (String → ArrayList) to an ArrayList

Tags: java, iteration, hash-map

I have one `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` and I want to concatenate a key with every item in its `ArrayList`.

Consider the following demo program:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map1 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

        ArrayList<String> map11 = new ArrayList<String>();
        map11.add("a");
        map11.add("b");
        map1.put("1", map11);

        ArrayList<String> map12 = new ArrayList<String>();
        map12.add("c");
        map12.add("d");
        map1.put("2", map12);

ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> ent : map1.entrySet()) {
            ArrayList<String> ls = ent.getValue();
            for (String string : ls) {
                finalList.add(ent.getKey()+" = "+string);
            }
        }
```

This is working fine and giving expected output. The value of `finalList` after executing program is:

> [1 = a, 1 = b, 2 = c, 2 = d]

If there is any better and faster way to do this, please let me know. In the actual project `ArrayList`, every `HashMap` entry contains thousands of items.

Comment: Do you really need a `List` as the result? Are you planning to serialize it? Do you need to know the total size? If not, you could consider implementing a custom [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Comment: yes I need list. But for knowledge can you give me link where I can find example of custom iterable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's really a list of entries that you want, then this is about as fast as it gets.

But it can be better:

- Use interface types instead of implementations, for example `List` instead of `ArrayList` and `Map` instead of `HashMap`
- Java 6 is no longer supported, and in Java 7 you should use the diamond operator to create new instances, for example: `Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();`
- Use better, more natural names, for example:

  - `entry` is better than `ent`
  - `list` is better than `ls`
- Use unit tests to verify your implementation

Based on the above, here's an alternative implementation:

```
public static List<String> concatMapEntries(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
    List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        List<String> list = entry.getValue();
        for (String string : list) {
            finalList.add(entry.getKey() + " = " + string);
        }
    }
    return finalList;
}
```

And unit test:

```
@Test
public void testExample() {
    Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> map11 = new ArrayList<>();
    map11.add("a");
    map11.add("b");
    map1.put("1", map11);

    List<String> map12 = new ArrayList<>();
    map12.add("c");
    map12.add("d");
    map1.put("2", map12);

    assertEquals("[1 = a, 1 = b, 2 = c, 2 = d]", concatMapEntries(map1).toString());
}
```

Comment: you said `Use interface types instead of implementations, for example List instead of ArrayList and Map instead of HashMap` what is reason behind it?

Comment: It's better to code against the most generic interface possible. For example the alternative implementation I gave you will work with a `TreeMap` with `LinkedList` values too, making it far more usable than the original.